# Effect of spontaneous transmutation of atom in crystal

Tags: electronic-configuration, crystallography, nuclear-chemistry

What happens to a compound when one of its atoms changes via spontaneous nuclear reaction to an atom with very different bonding? For example, beryllium-7 turns into lithium-7 with a half-life of 53 days. After 53 days half the divalent Beryllium in a crystal of BeF2 would be monovalent Lithium ions. Half of the flourine atome formerly bonded to the former Beryllium atoms would be "floating free", not something Fluorine is wont to do. What would actually happen? Would there be a fluorine ion trapped in the crystal? A flourine atom? Some kind of radical?

Plainly energies available from  the nuclear reaction are orders of magnitude larger than anything that would ever be available in chemical bond energies, so even crazy unstable species have plenty of energy to form.

Comment: Good question, this idea has bothered me for years. Still nobody ever answered it definitely.

Comment: Defects in crystals are quite well known. ‘Incredibly unstable’ isn’t quite what happens.

Comment: An extra unbonded fluorine in the middle of the crystal is actually pretty stable, much like a serial killer in a high-security prison cell.

Comment: @IvanNeretin - not quite the analogy that I would have used, but yes it quite likely finds a nice interstitial position.

Comment: @Chalo there is a brief discussion about this effect for Einsteinium compounds in section 12.6 [here](http://radchem.nevada.edu/classes/rdch710/files/einsteinium.pdf)

Comment: For clarification: after 53 days, fully half of the crystal will contain these defects (half of the divalent beryllium will have turned to monovalent Lithium). This is not one serial killer in a cell. This is more like half the general population being serial killers.