# What happens to chemical bonds if the nucleus changes?

Tags: nuclear, nuclear-chemistry

Lets say I have some $\ce{PuF6}$ (with the Plutonium being $\ce{^{240}Pu}$). I take this $\ce{PuF6}$ and bombard it with neutrons. The $\ce{^{240}Pu}$ nuclei capture the neutrons, forming $\ce{^{241}Pu}$, which decays after some time to $\ce{^{241}Am}$. $\ce{AmF6}$ is not a stable molecule from what we know - we can't synthesize it in labs. So what exactly happens to the chemical bonds? $\ce{AmF4}$ seems stable - does a difluorine molecule just get "kicked" off?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/111356/effect-of-spontaneous-transmutation-of-atom-in-crystal

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/65809/what-happens-to-a-radioactive-carbon-dioxide-molecule-when-its-carbon-14-atom-de